# How does std::sort work with duplicated numbers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

When I was testing the std::sort function to deal with a vector filled with duplicated numbers, I found something really bewildering.

For example, here is a piece of c++ code.

```
#include <ctime>
#define startTime std::clock_t stTime = clock()
#define endTime std::clock_t edTime = clock()
#define processTime static_cast<double>(edTime - stTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    vector<int> v;
    while (i != 1000000) {
        v.push_back(2);
        ++i;
    }
    startTime;
    sort(begin(v), end(v), [](const int& lhs, const int& rhs) { return lhs <= rhs; });
    endTime;
    cout << processTime;
    system("pause");
}
```

When I didn't transmit the lambda expression including <= to the std::sort, everyting went well. However, various exceptions uccured when I actually did it. In this case, Segmentation Error occured. Sometimes the compiler failed to delete the elements in vector.

After throughly examination, I found something may happen in the STL files:

```
//stl_algo.h
  /// This is a helper function...
  template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Compare>
    _RandomAccessIterator
    __unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator __first,
              _RandomAccessIterator __last,
              _RandomAccessIterator __pivot, _Compare __comp)
    {
      while (true)
    {
      while (__comp(__first, __pivot))
        ++__first;
      --__last;
      while (__comp(__pivot, __last))
        --__last;
      if (!(__first < __last))
        return __first;
      std::iter_swap(__first, __last);
      ++__first;
    }
    }
```

Where `__pivot` is `__first+1` .

While comparing `__first` and `__pivot` , the statement is alway **true**, so we don't know where `__first` goes to.

Who can explain how does std::sort work in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

You have created an invalid comparator function with your lambda, should have used `<` instead of `<=`, otherwise `sort()` keeps swapping equal elements.

According to the reference for [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) a comparator must:

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) **which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second**.